# Disable "ding" sound when changing volume on Windows

Tags: windows, audio

Every time I change the audio level via Windows 7 Professional x64's Task Bar's audio control to up or down, Windows does a ding sound, which is quite annoying.

How do you disable this?

Comment: alternatively you can change volume with the hot keys on the keyboard - these don't make a noise (unlike the Mac)

Comment: @niico not sure about Win7, but on Win10, the arrow keys (<- and ->) on keyboard do make a noise. Are there any other hotkeys you can use?

Comment: Use the mouse wheel and you won't get any ding and retain the default ding sound systemwide. Never crossed my mind even though it's so logical. Thanks David Metcalfe for this (his comment is below Joe Taylor's answer but I felt moved to put it here too).

https://superuser.com/users/61471/david-metcalfe

Answer (score 89, accepted):

This is connected to the Default Beep sound in Windows. To disable it you need to set the default beep sound to None.

To do this:

1. Type sound into your Start menu and pick the Sound item from the search results.
2. On the Sounds tab, select "Default Beep" in the list, and set it to None using the dropdown box below (Top of the list)

Warning - You will no longer get any other sound notifications for events that use the default beep.

[image]

Comment: This still works in Windows 10.

Comment: Alternately if one doesn't want to lose the Beep sound system-wide, as Joe warned, you can adjust the volume slider with the mouse wheel and it won't trigger the ding sound.

Comment: I am on Windows 10, and this didn't work for me

Comment: @David Metcalfe Thank you so much, using the mouse wheel to change the volume solve this incriminating sound from being activated at 5 in the morning when you want to change the volume without gf waking up

Comment: @TokeFaurby If you happen to run Windows through Bootcamp you can disable it by right-clicking on sound icon, opening mixer and disabling the sound for Bootcamp Manager.

Comment: none of these solutions work on my bluetooth speaker.

Comment: It doesn't work on this computer.  The "default beep" doesn't seem to be associated with volume adjustments.

Comment: @TokeFaurby I added more specific instructions in a [new answer](https://superuser.com/a/1595586/494173).

Comment: @DavidMetcalfe you saved the day, thanks a heap, man!

Comment: @DavidMetcalfe that's so helpful! I've added that as a separate community wiki answer so it's more visible https://superuser.com/a/1670314/17025

Comment: This does not make any difference for bluetooth speakers

Answer (score 12):

**More specific instructions for Windows 10**

1. Search for and open "Sound settings"
2. On the right under Related Settings, click "Sound Control Panel". If you use Windows 11, you won't have that option. Instead, click "More sound settings".
3. Click the Sounds tab
4. Select "Default Beep" in the Program Events list
5. At the bottom, where it says "Sounds", a .wav file is selected (*Windows Background.wav* by default). Change this to (None).
6. Apply changes.

This will save a new Sound Scheme (for me it was called "Windows Default (modified)". If you want to undo your changes, you can either set the sound back to what it was, or you can change the Sound Scheme back to "Windows Default".

Comment: No change at all.

Comment: @PeterKionga-Kamau I added an update for Windows 11, since there isn't a "Sound Control Panel" option. Are you on Windows 10, or 11?

Comment: In Windows 11, the related Program Event is "Notification".

Answer (score 3):

If you want to **turn off the changing volume sound running Windows 10 through Bootcamp** (on a Mac machine) the accepted solution might not work for you. You can then disable the sound by right-clicking on a speaker icon (bottom right corner of the screen) -> Open Volume Mixer -> Remove volume for the Bootcamp Manager. If you don't see Bootcamp Manager there try to adjust volume with your keyboard buttons and it shall appear.

(according to [apple forum](https://discussions.apple.com/message/15856034#message15856034))

Comment: This worked in Windows 10 running on my Macbook Pro. Lowered the volume of the Bootcamp Manager in the mixer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Although you can remove this sound by removing the Default Beep, as indicated in other answers, this also affects other notifications. However, (as [david-metcalfe](https://superuser.com/users/61471/david-metcalfe) pointed out in [this comment](https://superuser.com/questions/351134/disable-ding-sound-when-changing-volume-on-windows#comment1618464_351136))  if you change the volume by clicking on the volume icon in the Start bar and then using the mouse wheel to scroll up and down, the beep is not produced. This may be a more practical way to avoid the sounds when on a call etc.

Comment: When using Bluetooth speakers it makes no difference how you change the volume or what you disable in the sound settings, the beep is always present for every single volume increment.