# Can I force Windows sounds to *always* use the default speaker?

Tags: windows-10, audio, speakers, system-sounds

I'm trying to wrangle some control over how audio alerts ("sounds") work on my Windows 10 laptop. This device has a Bluetooth connected speaker, and everyone in my household is annoyed when an alert plays over these speakers in loud, high-fidelity.

I saw in [another Q&A](https://superuser.com/q/351134/466273) that I can disable these alert sounds altogether, but **is there a way for me to force system-related sounds to *always* play through my laptop's built-in speaker**, even when I have the Bluetooth speaker set as my playback device?

Comment: Not within Windows, I don't believe. Some specialized tools *may* give you some level of control over where sounds from specific sources are played, but I do not know for sure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change the audio output device in Firefox](https://superuser.com/questions/279313/change-the-audio-output-device-in-firefox)

Comment: @music2myear Unfortunately, no

Answer (score 1):

I have found a workaround that works for me.
In Sound settings -> App volume and device preferences set your laptop speakers as the default sound device

Then Route all programs to your bluetooth speakers except for the system sounds.
This works for me but is certainly not a clean solution.
Cheers